# Reproducing Script.Render() to output a view specific script in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm writing an MVC web application, and some of the JavaScript files really only need to be "included" in specific views.

Retrieving a list of the bundle items I need has been achieved, using the following code:

```
        HttpContext currentHttpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(currentHttpContext);

        BundleContext bundlecontext = new BundleContext(httpContext, BundleTable.Bundles, "~/bundles/");

        bundlecontext.EnableInstrumentation = false;

        var bundleList = bundlecontext.BundleCollection.ToList().Where(b => b.Path.StartsWith("~/bundles/" + HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower() + "_"));
```

Outputting the contents of each file, or just doing a <script src="[file]"></script> is fairly trivial, however, what I'm trying to output is the same as what Script.Render() outputs:

<script src="/bundles/bootstrap?v=2Fz3B0iizV2NnnamQFrx-NbYJNTFeBJ2GM05SilbtQU1"></script>

Is it possible to do this programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured this out, after looking at the source code for MVC I can see that you can just use Scripts.Render... which should have been obvious from the start >_<

```
    public static IHtmlString RenderScripts()
    {

        List<string> bundlePaths = new List<string>();
        HttpContext currentHttpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        var httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(currentHttpContext);

        BundleContext bundlecontext = new BundleContext(httpContext, BundleTable.Bundles, "~/bundles/");

        bundlecontext.EnableInstrumentation = false;

        var bundleList = bundlecontext.BundleCollection.ToList().Where(b => b.Path.StartsWith("~/bundles/" + HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString().ToLower() + "_"));

        foreach (Bundle bundleItem in bundleList)
        {
            bundlePaths.Add(bundleItem.Path);
        }

        return Scripts.Render(bundlePaths.ToArray());
    }
```